# Circuit Creation Failed: "CHANNEL_CLOSED"

Tags: circuit, configuration, python

I'm trying to create circuits using the Stem library and I keep getting the following error ...

```
controller.new_circuit(['711e9e5711a6e28e2a27de23b7c70c91d39908d0','D3E47F64C413410F24AD259905B0B748453CFA3C'],await_build=True)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 2005, in new_circuit
    return self.extend_circuit('0', path, purpose, await_build)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 2098, in extend_circuit
    raise stem.CircuitExtensionFailed("Circuit failed to be created: %s" % circ.reason, circ)
stem.CircuitExtensionFailed: Circuit failed to be created: CHANNEL_CLOSED
```

It's really odd, because I've been using this method to create circuits for a long time, and all the sudden it's not working anymore. I'm sure that I've got my controller set up and authenticated correctly, and I'm sure that Tor is running on the correct ports and everything. Does anyone know what this CHANNEL_CLOSED error means, or why it might be occurring? Thanks!

Comment: At a guess maybe one of those relays was having availability issues at the time. Is this happening consistently or was it transient? I'm guessing that you haven't upgraded or changed Tor since it was previously working?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this same issue at some point... it turns out my network suddenly began blocking Tor, which is why the channel was being closed immediately during the circuit extension process.